# Looking for a good introduction to Medieval Jewish Philosophy

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

I'm interested in learning more about the different philosophical opinions amongst the early Rishonim, such as Maimonides, R' Yehuda Halevi, etc.

I was hoping someone could recommend a good resource. I'd prefer as many of the following conditions:

1. Written from an Orthodox point of view
2. Easy to read
3. Geared towards the layman
4. No knowledge of greek philosophy required (bonus if the greek philosophical ideas are explained as well)
5. comprehensive
6. I'd prefer english, but an easy to read hebrew would also be acceptable.

I've found some books on Amazon, but don't know anything about them. If you've read them, please let me know if you recommend them, or if there are others that are not listed which you'd recommend.

1. [Dogma in Mediaeval Jewish Thought: From Maimonides to Abravanel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0197100449) by Menachem Kellner
2. [An Introduction to Medieval Jewish Philosophy (Introductions to Religion)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1845117484) by Daniel Rynhold
3. [Jewish Philosophy in the Middle Ages](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/193484327X) by Raphael Jospe

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38657/recommend-book-on-jewish-philosophy-contrasting-secular-philosophies

Comment: similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67947/sefer-of-jewish-philosophy

Comment: There's a 3-volume textbook called [פילוסופיה יהודית בימי הביניים](http://openbooks.openu.ac.il/#!/search_results/fields/32,32,20/types/2,3/languages/1) (in Hebrew) that can also be viewed online, but I haven't read it, so I can't say if it meets your criteria

Comment: @ba: It appears that Jewish Philosophy in the Middle Ages by Raphael Jospe is a translation of that textbook, but that's a great link.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend the pioneering work 'A History of Mediaeval Philosophy' by the eminent professor [Isaac Husik](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Husik) (available on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1162931981) or at [JudaicaUsed](http://stores.ebay.com/Jewish-Bookshop/_i.html?_nkw=History%20mediaeval%20philosophy&submit=Search&_sop=10&_cqr=true&_rusck=1&_nkwusc=History%20mediavel%20philosophy&_sid=51151348&_sc=1)). The book is a thorough and comprehensive anthology of all the classical works of the Jewish philosophers.

@Dennis pointed out that you can [read the book online at archive.org](https://archive.org/details/historyofmediaev00husi).

Comment: I read some reviews online that said it was not an easy read. Have you read it yourself? Do you agree?

Comment: I have read it, as you say, not an easy read, but I do recommend it.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, I've read [a lot] of it and would agree that it's not an easy read. However I'd attribute that drawback not to the author or his style but to the content. The ideas, concepts and locution of these medieval writings are themselves the issue making it difficult to be given over in contemporary English. As for the book, it's a wonderful presentation and translation of the classics.